# Xcode add dependencies to "Project" OR "Target" (difference?)

Tags: xcode, dependencies, monorepo, swift-package-manager, workspace

What's the difference between ***project* dependencies** and ***target* dependencies**?

- ***Project*** dependencies can be added here:

[image: project dependencies]

- ***Target*** dependencies can be added here:

[image: target dependencies]

---

- in the case of external dependencies (via URL), do we need to add it to *both* project and target, or is one of those enough?
- in the case of local dependencies (via the workspace), do we need to add it to *both* project and target, or is one of those enough?